# Can't set width of a List to 0 in landscape

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to do sliding sidepanel with list. And the problem is that on devices with safearea guide, I can't set width of a list to 0 in landscape orientation.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Spacer()
        List {
            Text("1")
            Text("2")
        }
        .frame(width:0)
    }
    .background(Color.green)
  }
}
```

In portrait mode it looks like:

[image]

In landscape:

[image]

Any idea how to hide the list completely?

On the devices without safe area everything works well without issues.

The workaround, I found, is to add e.g.

```
Rectangle().frame(width: 0)
```

to the same HStack, then the list is not shown at all in all conditions, but this looks weird.

**Update from Jun 10th:**
I've been discussing this issue with Apple DTS team, and they confirmed, that I'm observing a system bug (now reported to the engineering team via FB7729714).
From other side, they pointed me that setting width of a view would cause relayout of child views, and thus setting to 0 is even more complicated thing. Therefore recommended is to work with position and offset for such cases as sliding views.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why does the `List` has to be visible on the screen?

Comment: @pawello2222, as I wrote at the beginning, in my app I have a sidepanel, which is closed or opened (sliding out or in from the right) by pressing a control button. Everything is nice and smooth. But during testing I found that in landscape mode on iPhoneX-like devices, the sidepanel is not completely hidden, it stays on the screen whatever whatever I do. The problem is only when a List is inside of the panel.
Interestingly enough - if I add Rectangle().frame(width:0) to the same HStack, sidepanel closes well. If I add spacing (HStack(spacing:0) {...) - again, the list is "unhideable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how exactly your code looks as you didn't provide more information, but here is how you can implement a sliding menu in `SwiftUI` without additional hacks.

You show/hide the side panel using `GeometryReader`, `offset` and animating transition:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showMenu = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    MainView(showMenu: self.$showMenu)
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                        .offset(x: self.showMenu ? geometry.size.width : 0)
                        .disabled(self.showMenu ? true : false)
                    if self.showMenu {
                        MenuView()
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                            .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                    }
                }
            }
            .background(Color.red)
            .navigationBarTitle("Side Menu", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: (
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.showMenu.toggle()
                    }
                    }) {
                    Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                }
                ))
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct MainView: View {
    @Binding var showMenu: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation {
                self.showMenu = true
            }
        }) {
            Text("Show Menu")
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct MenuView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Item 1")
            Text("Item 2")
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(Color.green)
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    }
}
```

The full explanation of this code is in this tutorial: [How To Create A Side Menu In SwiftUI](https://blckbirds.com/post/side-menu-hamburger-menu-in-swiftui/).

Also you can try adding this to your `Views` to fill the whole screen:

```
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea()
```

Tested in Xcode 11.5. A slider disappears completely from the screen - I hope it's what you wanted to achieve.